# Iphone Image Processing Image APIS

Tags: iphone

I wanted to know about image processing APIs in Iphone like increasing or decreasing brightness of an image , rotating image ,scaling image etc. How can I achieve this in Iphone?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of relevant sample code in the GLImageProcessing example
You can download the source code from the following url

http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/samplecode/GLImageProcessing/listing12.html